# Secure MultiByteToWideChar Usage

Tags: c, winapi, unicode

I've got code that used MultiByteToWideChar like so:

```
wchar_t * bufferW = malloc(mbBufferLen * 2);
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, mbBuffer, mbBufferLen, bufferW, mbBufferLen);
```

Note that the code does not use a previous call to MultiByteToWideChar to check how large the new unicode buffer needs to be, and assumes it will be twice the multibyte buffer.

My question is if this usage is safe? **Could there be a default code page that maps a character into a 3-byte or larger unicode character, and cause an overflow?** While I'm aware the usage isn't exactly correct, I'd like to gauge the risk impact.

Comment: You are specifying the buffer size correctly so nothing can go wrong.  Whether the converted string actually fits is secondary and has nothing to do with the encoding or the codepoint values, you'll get ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER if it doesn't.  You'd be wise to not risk this failure mode but that decision is entirely up to you.

Comment: @Olaf no MCVE needed here. It's Win32 and all relevant information has been provided.

Comment: Sorry for not including the correct tag, and thanks @HansPassant for the answer.

Comment: There is no character, whose UTF-16 encoding is 3 bytes in length. Unless you are dealing with a platform where a byte is an even multiple of an octet. Windows isn't.

Answer (score 3):

> Could there be a default code page that maps a character into a 3-byte or larger [sequence of wchar_t UTF-16 code units]

There is currently no ANSI code page that maps a single byte to a character outside the BMP (ie one that would take more than one 2-byte codeunit in UTF-16).

No single multi-byte ANSI character can ever be encoded as more than two 2-byte codeunits in UTF-16.  So, at *worse*, you will never end up with a UTF-16 string that has more than 2x the length of the input ANSI string (not counting the null-terminator, which does not apply in this case since you are passing explicit lengths), and at *best* you will end up with a UTF-16 string that has fewer `wchar_t` characters than the input string has `char` characters.

For what it's worth, Microsoft are [endeavouring](http://www.siao2.com/2005/02/06/368081.aspx) not to develop the ANSI code pages any further, and I suspect the NLS file format would need changes to allow it, so it's pretty unlikely that this will change in future. But there is no firm API promise that this will definitely always hold true.